# I have this error in GDX

Tags: libgdx

It worked!
But when I check in my Bullet class it doesn't work and gives me an error!

This error:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: #iterator() cannot be used nested. at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array$ArrayIterator.hasNext(Array.java:577)
>       at  com.myflappyoyun.game.states.PlayState.update(PlayState.java:53)
>       at   com.myflappyoyun.game.states.GameStateManager.update(GameStateManager.java:25)
>       at com.myflappyoyun.game.FlappyDemo.render(FlappyDemo.java:36)
>       at   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
>       at   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)

The process finished with exit code 0

```js
public class PlayState extends state {
    private static final int TUBE_SPACING = 125;
    private static final int TUBE_COUNT = 4;
    private static final int GROUND_Y_OFFSET = -50 ;

    private Bird bird;
    private Texture bg;
    private Texture ground;
    private Vector2 groundPos1 , groundPos2 ;
    private Array<Tube> tubes ;

    public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        bird= new Bird(50 , 300);
        cam.setToOrtho(false, FlappyDemo.WIDTH/ 2, FlappyDemo.HEIGHT/ 2);
        bg = new Texture("bg.png");
        ground = new Texture("ground.png");
        groundPos1 = new Vector2(cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth / 2, GROUND_Y_OFFSET);
        groundPos2 = new Vector2((cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth / 2) + ground.getWidth(), GROUND_Y_OFFSET);

        tubes = new Array<Tube>();

        for (int i = 1; i < TUBE_COUNT ; i++) {
            tubes.add(new Tube(i * (TUBE_SPACING + Tube.TUBE_WIDTH)));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleInput() {
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched())
            bird.jump();

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        handleInput();
        updateGround();
        bird.update(dt);
        cam.position.x = bird.getPosition().x + 80 ;

        for (Tube tube : tubes) {
            if (cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth/ 2) > tube.getPosTopTube().x + tube.getTopTube().getWidth()){
                tube.reposition(tube.getPosTopTube().x + ((Tube.TUBE_WIDTH + TUBE_SPACING) * TUBE_COUNT));
            }
            if (tube.collides(bird.getBounds()))
                gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
        }
        if (bird.getPosition().y <= ground.getHeight() + GROUND_Y_OFFSET)
            gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
    cam.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(bg , cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2), 0);
        sb.draw(bird.getTexture(), bird.getPosition().x,bird.getPosition().y);
        for (Tube tube : tubes) {
            sb.draw(tube.getTopTube(), bird.getPosition().x, tube.getPosTopTube().y);
            sb.draw(tube.getBottomTube(), tube.getPosBotTube().x, tube.getPosBotTube().y);
        }
        sb.draw(ground, groundPos1.x, groundPos1.y);
        sb.draw(ground, groundPos2.x, groundPos2.y);
        sb.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        bg.dispose();
        bird.dispose();
        ground.dispose();
        for (Tube tube : tubes)
            tube.dispose();
        System.out.println("Play State Disposed");

    }
    private void updateGround() {
        if (cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2) > groundPos1.x + ground.getWidth())
            groundPos1.add(ground.getWidth()*2, 0);
        if (cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2) > groundPos2.x + ground.getWidth())
            groundPos2.add(ground.getWidth()*2, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Collections Try using normal loop with indexes instead of forEach loop in your `PlayState.update()` method

Comment: i'm new in android develop , can you write the right code to me?

Comment: Just replace `for (Tube tube : tubes)` with `for (int i = 1; i < TUBE_COUNT ; i++)`.

Comment: Also you probably need to call `return;` after `gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));` to stop iterating through `tubes` after colliding.

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like you should probably just change 'tubes' to the type of ArrayList, like the following:

```
ArrayList<Tube> tubes = new ArrayList<Tubes>();
```

You might be better off with a different type of collection.  Check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for some ideas depending on how you ultimately use 'tubes'.  Look at the implementing classes of 'List'

Comment: i'm new in android develop , can you write the right code to me?

Comment: The code you need to change is written in my answer.  I strongly suggest doing some Java tutorials and get a good feel for the language before digging in to a library.  It will save you time and make your code better in the long run.